# Adding more data to a text file (Actionscript 3)

Tags: actionscript-3, export

Currently using:

Code:

```
        stream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
        stream.writeUTFBytes(data1);
        stream.close();
```

To export some basic data to a simple text file. However when I use this code it overwrites the previous data. Is there a way to modify this so it just adds to it as opposed to overwriting it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `FileMode.APPEND` to append the write operation.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileMode.html